# Erlang BPMN 2 Parser

Tags: erlang, bpmn

I'm writing BPMN (Business Process Model and Notation) engine for Erlang. I've created parser, that gets business process definition from xml, creates amount of different records and links between them. Now, i need to create gen_fsm skeleton, based on data described above. Can you point me to right direction for code generation in Erlang? Thanks in adnvance

Answer (score 0):

my suggestion is to create a rebar template (1), then you can simply create an app based on the skeleton you have.

(1): https://github.com/rebar/rebar/wiki/Template-support

Comment: Good idea, thanks, i thought about it, but my problem is that skeleton is not static. In other words, skeleton will be changed from process to process and have different amount of states (functions)

Comment: I think values should be dynamic not skeleton. for example, webmachine, which contains a script that lets us initialize a project and what it wants from us are "name" and "prefix", so these two can be anything but the skeleton is always static.
however, I know what you need is somehow different, but the idea is to have a template and change its values.